# Windows 10 - Remove default pinned items from the taskbar

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am not a big fan of the "pinnable" taskbar feature that was introduced in Windows 7 and which has carried through to Windows 10.

I tend to customise back to classic taskbar items.  However, in Windows 10 there seems to be default items (Microsoft Edge and File Explorer) pinned which cannot be removed (normally which I do through a right click -> Unpin):

[image: Windows 10 pinned items]

Is it possible to remove these?

**EDIT:**

Right clicking produces a menu with no "unpin" options.  I also do not have Edge or File Explorer running:

[image: Unpin Edge]

Comment: You should have unpin this program from the taskbar on the right click menu. Based on the red underlines in your screenshot the icons are still showing since you have instances of Edge and File Explorer open.

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT: Please see my edit.  There is no unpin option and I do not have these applications running. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst I see that you have tried to right click, the Unpin option is available for me when I right-click:

[image]

I have tried this in Win 10 Enterprise RTM. 
Edge is running, with a couple of tabs open.

- What version of Win10 are you running?
- Can you try same again with Edge running and a few pages open? (long shot)

---

This also "works on my machine" for unpinning folder explorer too:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is my version of Windows 10.  It's the Insider Preview, Build 10162.

Comment: I can pin and unpin other items just like you have described above, just not with Edge and File Explorer.

Comment: I still have an Insider Preview VM running in Azure, I'll check that and let you know...

Comment: I've checked this on my Insider Preview edition too - The Edge icon is not in the task bar and the file-explorer right-click does have an "unpin" option too. This was the most recent IP version, created from the Azure Win10 VS2015 image just last week.

Comment: Thanks for checking. It should then be rectified once updated to the RTM.

Comment: I hope that works for you (BTW I don't think that you can update an IP installation, you have to create a new installation for RTM)

Answer (score 0):

August 12th... I can't right click on any icons in the taskbar. I currently have the search icon, File Explorer icon, Firefox, Chrome, CCleaner, and "Edge"... no menus appear for any of them. I will never use Edge or whatever the latest incarnation of IE is. No unpin option, no menu at all. Just installed Win10 last night.

edit:  Restarted, turns out there were updates I was unaware of. I am able to pin and unpin as usual... problem is fixed.

Comment: I had this same problem just now, and used the same solution (of restarting).  I didn't seem to see any "updates" being installed but after the restart I was able to bring up the menus.  Thanks.